# Save Canvas Jquery into database ASP.NET C#

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html5-canvas

I am using Asp.Net webforms to save canvas (signatures) JQuery into SQL server server. Can somebody suggest me how could I do that. What type of feild I should required to save it into db.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to save the entire canvas to the database as a Mime64 encoded string. The field type would be a varchar(MAX). You can display them by prefixing the string with data:image/png,mime64, and place that in the SRC attribute of an IMG tag.

We have also stored them in vector form as a JSON string, but we had requirements to resize the signature while retaining image quality.

Comment: Accept answer when happy with it. That will improve the chances of your future questions being answered.